# path_helper and zsh

Tags: zsh, path

I read that Apple, instead of jamming more and more `PATH` variable variations to the end of shell profile file, created `path_helper` binary so that it could expand `PATH` variable automatically by reading path lists from `/etc/paths.d/` directory.

Also - this file generates output only for csh and bash (`-c` and `-s` flags accordingly). There is no output for `zsh` (although zsh being somewhat bash compatible - I understand that).

I am using zsh. I have `/etc/zshenv` file which contains following lines:

```
# system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

It takes about half a second when I open terminal or its new tab for that process to complete. There is only one file with single path (`/usr/X11/bin`). How much am I risking if I remove `/etc/zshenv` at all? Would it be enough to put aforementioned path to my `.zshrc` or `.zshenv` files?

Comment: Are you sure the half second (which I believe really is annoying) is due to this `path_helper` call?  I suspect it could just be `zsh`s start-up time, `bash` takes a moment, too.  While adding `PATH` entries in the usual way should do the same job, I doubt a little `path_helper` needs that much longer.  (Easy test: `setopt noglobalrcs` in `~/.zshenv`)

Comment: @sr_ - yes, I can see the process title in the terminal window's titlebar or tab itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Have you seen this, superuser.com on a similar issue?](https://superuser.com/questions/31403/how-can-i-speed-up-terminal-app-or-iterm-on-mac-osx/31612#31612)  The linked [blog post](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2009/04/01/slow-opening-terminal-windows/) says (and I quote almost the complete post):

> `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, which Mac OS X runs every time a login shell is created, is really slow. (In particular, I think the slowness is in `[[ "$NEWPATH" = *(*:)${p}*(:*) ]]`.) My Terminal windows were taking about four seconds to open. By removing the files in /etc/paths.d and putting their contents directly into my $PATH in .bash_profile, Terminal windows now load instantly.

The discussion also includes a link to a [replacement written in Perl, `github.com/mgprot/path_helper`](http://github.com/mgprot/path_helper) (no idea about its speed, tho).

**Edit:** From the aforementioned blog post's comments - [a patch to `path_helper`](https://gist.github.com/123525) that should be another way to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! AFAIK, the path_helper on my system is actual universal binary (for i386 and x64_86 architectures). So I'm not sure the patch will help me. Although now at least I'm confident enough to remove all the files from /etc/paths.d/

Comment: I have just removed all files from /etc/paths.d/ and terminal starts instantly (after rebooting to ensure no warm startup)!

Answer (score 4):

I know what's following has no impact on the speed of starting a new terminal.  However it's bitten me so I thought I'd put in my two cents.

I think it's actually questionable that this call (to path_helper) is in zshenv (which is called for all shells, not just login shells).  For other shells the path_helper call is instead in /etc/profile or in /etc/csh.login -- which are called only for login shells.

This becomes a problem if you run the 'screen' utility under zsh.  'screen' will not start a login shell, but will rather inherit environment from the calling shell.  But it will still call /etc/zshenv and bu extension path_helper.

As it happens, path_helper will not only grab PATH candidates from /etc/paths.d, but if there is an existing PATH when it's called, it will actively manipulate this PATH -- it will strip out components that it found in /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d and prepend them.  Thus if you have put ${USER}/bin or /usr/local/bin at the head of PATH (because you want your own programs to be found first) then this will not work inside a 'screen' session.

My suggested fix to my own problem is to rename /etc/zshenv to /etc/zprofile (currently nonexistent) but I'm worried that this will have ill effects... there *might* be a reason why the zsh implementation on OS X has this call in /etc/zshenv, and it will for sure be broken when the next OS comes out and I will have forgotten all about my fix.

Anyone else seen this?  Or have any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about `PATH` being manipulated. I think I've always been able to put what I want at the head of `PATH`. Then again, I generally do that in my `.zshrc` file, after path_helper has already done its work.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I know this answer is ancient, but it seems that in OSX El Capitan the call to `path_helper` has been moved from `/etc/zshenv ` to `/etc/zprofile`

Comment: Yeah, this is an extremely stupid thing to do. Lost countless of hours debugging why a makefile doesn't work when zsh is used as the shell?! Guess what - the PATH was always reset so that the commands were executed from wrong locations. If you have this piece of ... in `zshenv` better to remove it asap and/or move to `/etc/zprofile`.